# C# App.config - Alterar endereço do BD em tempo de instalação

Tags: c#, deploy, app.config

Tenho um aplicação C# desktop que ao ser instalada em um pc, deve acessar um BD Mysql que está  em outra máquina. O endereço do servidor do BD é configurado no arquivo `App.config` . 
Por solicitação do cliente, no momento da instalação eu preciso permitir que o usuário configure os parâmetros de acesso ao BD. 
Como posso gerar um dialog no momento da instalação, para que o usuário possa digitar o endereço do servidor, o usuário e a senha que devem ser utilizados para acessar o BD? Com esses valores, eu preciso alterar o arquivo App.config para que a aplicação após ser instalada acesse corretamente o BD. Criei um projeto de instalação (InstallShield), mas não achei onde posso criar essa funcionalidade

Comment: O sistema tem uma tela de "login"? Se sim, você pode fazer essa configuração nessa tela, ou seja, adicione campos para o usuário informar os parâmetros ou um menuzinho para fazer isso.

Comment: Esperava que alguém desse uma dica melhor, mas o único jeito que eu imagino seria executar um programa após a instalação para fazer a configuração.

Comment: Precisa ser no App.Config? Não pode ser em algum lugar mais simples, como um arquivo .ini?

Answer (score 1):

Em minhas aplicações na tela de login tem um Combobox onde o mesmo seleciona entre conexões cadastradas no app.config da aplicação. Ao lado do ComboBox tenho um botão que dá acesso a uma tela onde a pessoa pode cadastrar "Conexões", sendo que estas conexões são lidas/escritas diretamente no app.config da aplicação. Utilizo uma classe que realiza este acesso, adicionando e recuperando as ConnectionStrings. Abaixo esta classe:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

/// <summary>
///   Classe de manipulaçao do arquivo app.config
/// </summary>
public class AppConfigConStrings
{
    #region Instancias

    private const string strCaminhoExecutavel = "[caminho do executável]";

    private readonly Configuration pcfgConfiguration =
        ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(strCaminhoExecutavel);

    #endregion

    #region Metodos

    /// <summary>
    ///   Alimentar componente ICM_Combobox com as conexões existentes no App.config
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cboComboBox"> Componente a ser alimentado </param>
    /// <returns> </returns>
    public bool AlimentarComboConexoes(ComboBox cboComboBox)
    {
        try
        {
            ConnectionStringSettingsCollection lcscConexoesDisponiveis =
                ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(strCaminhoExecutavel).
                    ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings;
            if (lcscConexoesDisponiveis.Count > 0)
            {
                cboComboBox.Items.Clear();
                foreach (ConnectionStringSettings lcssconexao in lcscConexoesDisponiveis)
                {
                    cboComboBox.Items.Add(lcssconexao.Name);
                }

                if (cboComboBox.Items.Count > 0)
                    cboComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception lex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(lex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///   Quebrar string de conexão para recuperar valores.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="strNomeConexao"> Nome da string de conexão </param>
    public bool RecuperarValoresStringConexao(string strNomeConexao)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(strCaminhoExecutavel).
                    ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[strNomeConexao] != null)
            {
                string lstrConexao =
                    ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(strCaminhoExecutavel).
                        ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[strNomeConexao].ConnectionString;

                List<String> lstDadosConexao = new List<string>(lstrConexao.Split(new[] { '=', ';' }));
                for (int lintIndice = 0; lintIndice < lstDadosConexao.Count; lintIndice += 2)
                {
                    lstDadosConexao[lintIndice] = "";
                }

                lstDadosConexao.RemoveAll(predicate => predicate == "");

                // Tratamento a se realizar com os dados da conexão.
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception lex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(lex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///   Salvar Conexão
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="strDatasource"> Fonte de dados </param>
    /// <param name="strBancoDados"> Banco de dados </param>
    /// <param name="strUserId"> Usuario </param>
    /// <param name="strSenha"> Senha </param>
    /// <param name="strNomeConexao"> Nome Conexão </param>
    /// <returns> </returns>
    public bool SalvarConnectionStringSQLServer(string strDatasource, string strBancoDados, string strUserId,
                                       string strSenha, string strNomeConexao)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder lsqlsbconnectionBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                DataSource = strDatasource,
                InitialCatalog = strBancoDados,
                UserID = strUserId,
                Password = strSenha,
                IntegratedSecurity =
                    string.IsNullOrEmpty(strUserId.Trim())
            };

            if (RecuperaValorConexao(strNomeConexao) != null)
                return false;

            // Criar Conexão
            pcfgConfiguration.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Add(
                new ConnectionStringSettings
                {
                    Name = strNomeConexao,
                    ConnectionString = lsqlsbconnectionBuilder.ConnectionString,
                    ProviderName = "System.Data.SqlClient"
                });

            // Salvar Conexão
            pcfgConfiguration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception lex)
        {
            throw new Exception(lex.Message);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Exclua a conexão com o nome informado do arquivo de configuração.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="strNomeConexao">Nome da Conexão</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool RemoverConexao(string strNomeConexao)
    {
        if (pcfgConfiguration.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[strNomeConexao] != null)
        {
            pcfgConfiguration.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Remove(strNomeConexao);
            pcfgConfiguration.Save();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retorna o Numero de Conexões do App.config
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public int RetornaNumeroConexoes()
    {
        return pcfgConfiguration.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Count;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="strNomeConexao"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string RecuperaValorConexao(string strNomeConexao)
    {
        try
        {
            return pcfgConfiguration.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[strNomeConexao].ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }

    #endregion
}
```

Com a conexão selecionada, basta configurar o meu acesso para utilizar a ConnectionString desejada. Isso vai depender muito de como é feita a conexão.

Em meu caso utilizo o EntityFramework, portanto incluo o código:

```
Database.Connection.ConnectionString = strConexaoAtiva;
```

Se estiver usando ADO.NET, provavelmente voce esta usando a classe MySQLConnection, portanto o código deve ser algo como:

```
try
{
    conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();

    //Setando a ConnectionString
    conn.ConnectionString = strConexaoAtiva;

    conn.Open();
}
catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Vide documentação no site: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-open.html